# Add filter body_class to header.php without body tag

Tags: php, wordpress

In the theme check of my website I saw an error saying that the filter body_class was not found. I took a look at the support page of the plugin I´m using (https://support.fancyproductdesigner.com/support/solutions/articles/5000582912-using-the-debug-mode-to-inspect-any-missing-hooks-in-woocommerce-product-pages) and it says:

Missing hook: body_class
If you are seeing this information instead of the Product Designer:
Sorry! But the product designer is not adapted for your device. Please use a device with a larger screen!
It means an important hook is missing in your theme. You need to add following code to the body HTML tag in the header.php your theme.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

I tried to add the code to the header.php file, which has this content:

```
<?php

// =============================================================================
// HEADER.PHP
// -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// The site header.
// =============================================================================

x_get_view( 'header', 'base' );
```

But honestly, for some reasons it doesn´t help. Can someone show me which is the right way to do it?

Many thanks

Comment: what theme are you using?

Comment: Looks like you might find the base html here `wp-content\themes\x\framework\views\header\base.php`

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, that was my thought. The script is in effect already there, but the theme says anyway, that the code is missing.